# How to use FRVP In making indicator

Tags: pine-script, indicator

I want to add FRVP to my range indicator how to add it? As the source code is not visible?

I tried to get FRVP from other source but couldn’t.  Can someone help how to get FRVP source code so that I can add frvp in my range indicator

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.